# Add 'Review this product' in the Product listing Page (catalogue grid view page)

Tags: magento2.3.2

I am using Magento 2.3.2 with custom theme. I want to add 'Review this product' in the Product listing view when there are no reviews. In the file

> app/design/frontend/(vendor)/(theme-name)/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

I have tried adding this:

```
<?php if( count( $this->getReviewsCollection() ) > 0  ): ?>
<?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType) ?>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="jag-reviews-text"><a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product-review">Review this product</a></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But I get this error:this returns:

> Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /home/iperqer/public_html/app/design/frontend/iperQ/market/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml on line 72 plus a bunch of other code.

Any Ideas about how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

PHP 7.2 throws error if parameter passed to the count function is empty.
To get rid of this problem, you can change:

```
count($this->getReviewsCollection()) > 0
```

to

```
is_array($this->getReviewsCollection()) && count($this->getReviewsCollection()) > 0
```

This should solve the problem you are having.

**Update after @jonnie's comment on Oct 10, 2019:**

Instead of:

```
$this->getReviewsCollection()
```

try:

```
$this->getReviewsCollection()->getItems()
```

Comment: Thank you. This fixes the error thank you but I guess ` is_array($this->getReviewsCollection()) && count($this->getReviewsCollection()) > 0 ` is not pickup up the review count because all the listings now return "Review this product". Any ideas as to the fix. I read somewhere that I should be looking at the file summary_short.phtml.

Comment: I also tried this `<?php if( is_array($this->getReviewsCount()) && count($this->getReviewsCount()) > 0  ): ?>
<?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType) ?>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="jag-reviews-text"><a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product-review">Review this product</a></div>
<?php endif; ?>` with the same results. ( all the listings now return "Review this product" )